# Error in package.json deploying Angular2 project on Azure using bitbucket

Tags: node.js, azure, angular, bitbucket, package.json

I am facing a issue deploying angular2 app on azure. I get an error on following line

```
"engines":{"node":"6.2.1"},
```

I have given this version as WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION has the value 6.2.1. Anyone having idea about this then please share.

Here is the error snapshot:
[image]

package.json looks as follows:

```
{
"name": "angular-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"engines":{"node":"6.2.1"},
"description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
"scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
"docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
"docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
"pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
"e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
"lint": "tslint ./app/*/.ts -t verbose",
"lite": "node_modules\.bin\lite-server",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
"test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
"tsc": "node_modules\.bin\tsc",
"concurrently": "node_modules\.bin\concurrently",
"tsc:w": "node_modules\.bin\tsc -w",
"typings": "node_modules\.bin\typings",
"webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"licenses": [
{
"type": "MIT",
"url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
}
],
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",

"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"systemjs": "0.19.39",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"zone.js": "^0.6.25",
"concurrently": "^3.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.3",
"typings": "^1.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^3.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.3",
"typings": "^1.4.0",

"canonical-path": "0.0.2",
"http-server": "^0.9.0",
"tslint": "^3.15.1",
"lodash": "^4.16.2",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"karma": "^1.3.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^3.3.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4"
},
"repository": {}
}
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Could you please provide the detailed error message you got?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct package.json for deploying Angular2 app on Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189386/correct-package-json-for-deploying-angular2-app-on-azure)

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your app in a server or a cloud, you should run it on a port provided with **process.env.PORT**, here is an example:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log('Example app is running!');
});
```

in your ***package.json*** file the start script is setting the app to run on port 3000 by default.

Comment: where should i add this code? and what about the error related to node version?

Comment: I never deployed an Angular 2 app yet, but you can find many instructions on the web to help you understand how to get your app ready for production.

Comment: By the way, I think this file **protractor.conf.js** is involved, it contains the base URL of your app.

Comment: ok. will try it but how to get rid of error on node engines in package.json

Comment: Try to set a static node server to serve your application (like MEAN apps) by setting an entry file (like app.js).

Answer (score 0):

From Angular js2 Documentary:

```
If Node.js and npm aren't already on your machine, install them. Our examples require node v4.x.x or higher and npm 3.x.x or higher. To check which version you are using, run node -v and npm -v in a terminal window.
```

Could you please check your npm version?

Comment: I have node version node version 6.3.1 and npm version 3.10.3 installed

Comment: :D could you provide your error message. I remember you gave it but I cannot see it now.