# Do we need to push node_modules on bitbucket

Tags: node.js, azure, angular, typescript, bitbucket

While pushing an angular2 app on bitbucket, do we need to also push node_modules and typings folder along? I have to deply the app on azure. As far as I understood from various articles that when we deploy on Azure then it runs <kbd>npm install</kbd> itself hence node_modules and typings folder get created. Please share on this.

Comment: No, I do not think you need to push the node_modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [Azure's documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/),

> Azure Cloud Services expect all modules to be installed on the development environment, and the node_modules directory to be included as part of the deployment package. It is possible to enable support for installing modules using package.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json files on Cloud Services, however this requires customization of the default scripts used by Cloud Service projects. For an example of how to accomplish this, see [Azure Startup task to run npm install to avoid deploying node modules](https://github.com/woloski/nodeonazure-blog/blob/master/articles/startup-task-to-run-npm-in-azure.markdown)

They also expand on this issue:

> When deploying the node_modules directory as part of your application, it will increase the size of the deployment compared to using a package.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json file; however, it does guarantee that the version of the modules used in production are the same as those used in development.

In terms of code management, [there](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/) [are](https://byjoeybaker.com/why-you-should-never-commit-node-modules-in-nodejs) [conflicting](http://www.letscodejavascript.com/v3/blog/2014/03/the_npm_debacle) [positions](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-put-node_modules-in-gitignore) whether the `node_modules` folder should or shouldn't be submitted to version control. What I can say is that after the [left-pad incident](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/) more and more people have been trending towards the "should commit" direction, myself included.

Should you want to follow this road, I suggest you take a look at both [shrinkwrap](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap), which locks the versions of the packages your dependencies themselves depend on, and [shrinkpack](https://github.com/JamieMason/shrinkpack) which saves the actual packages as `.tar` to avoid noisy commit changes.

Comment: thanks fmello for detailed explanation. could you pls have a look at one of my questions related to bitbucket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170273/error-deploying-angular2-project-on-azure-using-bitbucket

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to push the `node_modules` folder with your project. If you have it declared in your dependencies in your `package.json` then whoever clones your project and runs `npm install` will download the correct things. An easy way to declare to `package.json` is by using `--save` on installation.

Ex. `npm install bootstrap --save`

Answer (score 1):

No, `node_modules` and `typings` folders don't need to be pushed. `npm install` will install your dependencies into those folders.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice -  do not push node_modules to git repository.

To avoid problems with dependencies - use module like **shrinkwrap** (which locks down the versions of a package's dependencies)